# Why have a refresh_token with an OAuth2 Client Credentials grant type?

Tags: oauth2

Can someone explain to me the purpose of the `refresh token` when you're using the **Client Credentials** grant type with OAuth2? I'm confused because you can easily generate a new `access token` without one, so why bother?

For example, to get an `access token` you typically only need:

```
https://oauth.example.com/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET
```

So why would you ever use:

```
https://oauth.example.com/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN
```

Is a `refresh token` more applicable when using other grant types (eg. Resource Owner Password Credentials)?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer elsewhere (credit to [Florent Morselli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340580/oauth-client-credential-flow-refresh-tokens)):

### Explanation

The issuance of a refresh token with the  client credential grant has no benefit.
That is why the [RFC6749 section 4.4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.3) indicates `A refresh token SHOULD NOT be included`. Thus its issuance is at the discretion of the authorization server.

From my point of view an authorization server should never issue a refresh token with the client credentials grant as the access token issuance process will take an additional and unnecessary step:

Issuance with the client_credentials grant type:

- Step one: client authentication (client secret, assertion...)
- OK access token is issued

Issuance with the refresh_token grant type:

- Step one: client authentication (client secret, assertion...)
- Step two: refresh token verification (expiration time, associated client...)
- OK access token is issued